# Does not contain a definition...and no extension method

Tags: linq, entity-framework, dynamics-crm, linqpad

I am using linqpad4 with it's CRM 2011 plugin.
I get this error. How to fix it.
Does not contain a definition...and no extension method...

Comment: Can you post your answer as an actual answer and click the check mark next to it? It'll be a lot easier for people to find that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error means something is changed in CRM schema, customization is published and you're trying to use new attribute in query but LinqPad schema is not updated.

Select the connection from left navigation, Right click and select Connection Properties. Ont he dialog bottom left Click on Refresh Schema. This will update the schema. Now you can work with latest schema.